# I need to take the value of 'Citta' from this API and save it to a variable, how can i do that?

Tags: angular

This is the API:

```
0: {CodSoggetto: 22543, CognomeDenominazione: "STELLA", Nome: "ANTONIO", CF_PI: "STLNTN29S26C975F",…}
CF_PI: "STLNTN2G9S26C975F"
CNascita: "CONVERSANO"
CResidenza: "CONVERSANO"
Cap: "7054014"
Citta: "CONVERSANO"
CodSoggetto: 24543
Cognome: "STELLA"
Deceduto: "N"
Nome: "ANTONIO"
Residente: "S"
Sesso: "M"
```

this is my service:

```
getCitta(){

return this.http.get(`${this._host}/Contribuente`).pipe(map((res: any) => {
  this._Var = res.Citta;
  return this._Var;
}));
```

When i use 'this._Var' it says undefined.

Comment: Please read https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response and provide a generic describing the response shape. Then the *compiler* can help you.

Comment: could you provide a piece of code where you call `getCitta()` and a piece where you refering to `service._Var`?

Comment: @Andrei this how i call it:  `getCitta() { this.userService.getCitta().subscribe(res => this._var = res)
  }`

Comment: and is `this.userList` undefined after that?

Answer (score 0):

`http` always return an `Observable` (a stream to be subscribed).

I'd change your service's call like this:

```
getCitta(){
    return this.http.get(`${this._host}/Contribuente`);
}
```

And in your component you can declare the `citta` variable:

`public citta: string;`

that gets assigned by a method:

```
public getCitta(): void {
  this.service.getCitta().subscribe(data => {
    this.citta = data?.citta;
    // After this point citta has a value
  });

  console.log(this.citta); // this will print undefined
}
```

Comment: this.citta = data?.citta; it gives error at this line

Comment: this mean nothing. What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
getCF(): Observable<string> {

return this.http.get(`${this._host}/Contribuente`)
.pipe(
  map((res: any) => {
    if (typeof res === 'object') {
      if (res instanceof Array) {
        return res[5].Citta;
      }
     return res.Citta;
    }
  })
);
```

}